# Use diffie hellman key exchange algorithm to encrypt and decrypt files in python

Tags: python, encryption, cryptography, diffie-hellman

I want to implement an algorithm which will encrypt and decrypt files using diffie hellman algorithm but I am unable to find any solution for the same. Here is my diffie hellman code:

```
import pyDH
d1 = pyDH.DiffieHellman()
d2 = pyDH.DiffieHellman()
d1_pubkey = d1.gen_public_key()
d2_pubkey = d2.gen_public_key()
d1_sharedkey = d1.gen_shared_key(d2_pubkey)
d2_sharedkey = d2.gen_shared_key(d1_pubkey)
```

I want to encrypt files using this algorithm. Can anyone help me with this please?

Comment: Since Diffie-Hellman *only* generates a *shared public key*, you now have to use this key for the actual encryption, for example by using AES

Comment: As @linuskmr says, you now have a shared secret (well actually two as you've performed both ends of the key agreement - and they should be the same). Before using it as a key you should derive key material from it using a key derivation algorithm of your choice. Consider including into the KDF other 'random' information like the filename. Derive sufficient material for a key and IV/nonce, then use AES/GCM or some symmetric cipher.

Comment: If you want a well-designed, open-source package that does all that and more, consider: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/encryption-sdk/latest/developer-guide/python.html